# Solving $\sqrt{3x^2-2}+\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}= 3x-2 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I solve the equation  $$\sqrt{3x^2-2}+\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}= 3x-2$$
I know that it has two roots: $x=1$ and $x=3$.

Comment: Transport the square root and cube. Simplify, transport the square root and square. Then report to the authorities: torture is a crime. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Substituting $x = \sqrt{t^3+1}$ and twice squaring, we arrive to the equation
$$   36t^6-24t^5-95t^4+8t^3+4t^2-48t=0.$$ Its real roots are $t=0$ and $t=2$ (the latter root is found in the form $\pm \text{divisor}(48)/\text{divisor}(36)$), therefore $x=1$ and $x=3$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the functions: $f_{1},f_{2}:D\rightarrow\textbf{R}$, where $D = (-\infty,-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}]\cup[\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}, \infty) $,

$f_{1}(x)={\sqrt{3X^{2}-2}}+\sqrt[3]{x^{2}-1}$ and $f_{2}(x)=3x-2$.

For $x\leq-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$ $f_{1}$ is decreasing, $f_{2}$ is increasing and $f_{1}(-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}})>f_{2}(-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}})$, the equation has no negative solutions.

For $x\geq\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$, $f_{1}$ is concave ( $f''_{1}(x) < 0$ ) and $f_{2}$ is linear function, the equation has at most two roots, which are $x_{1}=2$ and $x_{2}=3$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt[3]{x^2-1} &= 3x-2 - \sqrt{3x^2-2}\\
\end{align}
$$
The step of cubing both sides has been omitted for space. It rearranges to:
$$
\begin{align}
54x^3 - 73x^2 + 18x + 5 &= 30x^2\sqrt{3 x^2-2} - 36x\sqrt{3 x^2-2} + 10\sqrt{3 x^2-2}\\
54x^3 - 73x^2 + 18x + 5 &= (30x^2 - 36x + 10)\sqrt{3 x^2-2}\\
\frac{54x^3 - 73x^2 + 18x + 5}{30x^2 - 36x + 10} &= \sqrt{3 x^2-2}\\
\end{align}
$$
$$
\frac{2916x^6 - 7884x^5 + 7273x^4 - 2088x^3 - 406x^2 + 180x + 25}{900 x^4-2160 x^3+1896 x^2-720 x+100} = 3x^2 - 2
$$

$$
2916x^6 - 7884x^5 + 7273x^4 - 2088x^3 - 406x^2 + 180x + 25 =\\
2700 x^6-6480 x^5+3888 x^4+2160 x^3-3492 x^2+1440 x-200\\
$$

$$
216 x^6-1404 x^5+3385 x^4-4248 x^3+3086 x^2-1260 x+225 = 0
$$

Now use the remainder and factor theorems to test for solutions, and you will find roots 1 and 3.